# PHP: how to update html text element, based on value from select element?

Tags: php, html

I have an an html form with only `<select>` element. Below the form I have a text box, I want to update the value of the text box based on the option selected in the form.

I am not sure if this is possible in PHP, I know I can do it with Javascript/Jquery, but I am working on a school project and its a PHP project. My teacher has done it but Im not sure if he used PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="books">
        <?php
            $books = simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
            foreach($books->book as $book){
                $code = $book->code;
                $title = $book->title;
                echo "<option value='$code'>$code: $title</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
    $choice = $_POST['books'];
    echo "<input type='text' value='$choice'>";
?>
```

When the page first loads I want the value from the selected option to be in the text box. I am not sure how I could go about doing this in PHP. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript is a far more likely solution! That will probably be what your teacher has used!

Comment: As Dane said, JS is solution. Use jQuery if you can. In few lines you'll your thing done. I can give you an example of it if you want.

Comment: @Dane Caswell its a PHP project, we have to use php.

Comment: If you are struggling to solve this problem, you should speak to your teacher. Copying a solution from SO wont help you learn.

Comment: @Steve Im not copying solutions, I am just asking how i could do this.

Comment: @user3898380 Well the 1st thing you need to do is make sure you understand the requirements of the project - whether or not javascript is allowed / required is an important part of the plan. In the real world, javascript would be at least part of the solution, but academic problems are usually designed to teach a certain subject, so may very well require a pure php answer

Comment: @user3898380 My answer below shows how to do it without a submit button.

Comment: thanks Fred -ii-, I was looking for a PHP solution to this. But doesnt look like there is one. So javascript or a submit button is the best solution.

Comment: @user3898380 Ok and you're welcome. I can do up a rewrite. I misunderstood when I read about the "I can do this in Javascript". I figure just adding a submit button would work, which was my original writeup, strangely enough.

Comment: @user3898380 Reload my answer under **Edit**.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I have got it working by using: onchange="this.form.submit()" in the form element. Thanks alot though.

Comment: @user3898380 You're welcome. I'm sure you can use a mix of both my answers. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**, as a pure PHP solution with a submit button, which will load data on initial page load then load data with the submit button as per selection.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="books">
        <?php
            $books = simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
            foreach($books->book as $book){
                $code = $book->code;
                $title = $book->title;
                echo "<option value='$code'>$code: $title</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>


<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : $books->book[0]->code;
    echo "<input type='text' value='$choice'>";
}

else{
$choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : $books->book[0]->code;
    echo "<input type='text' value='$choice'>";
}

?>
```

---

Original answer with `onchange`

The following would work, using Javascript and `getElementById` which would echo the selection in a text box using an `onchange` function.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="books" onchange="update_textbox()" id="id_books">
        <?php
            $books = simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
            foreach($books->book as $book){
                $code = $book->code;
                $title = $book->title;
                echo "<option value='$code'>$code: $title</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>

</form>

<?php 

    $choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : '';
    echo "<input type='text' value='$choice' id='showit'>";

?>

<script>
 function update_textbox(){
  var selectbox = document.getElementById('id_books');
  var id_books = selectbox[selectbox.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById('showit').value=id_books ;
 }
</script>
```

---

To load data into the text box at initial page load, use:

Replace:

```
$choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : '';
```

with:

```
$choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : $books->book[0]->code;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="books" onchange="javascript:document.form.submit();">
        <?php
            $books = simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
            foreach($books->book as $book){
                $code = $book->code;
                $title = $book->title;
                echo "<option value='$code'>$code: $title</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
    $choice = isset($_POST['books'])?$_POST['books']:'';
    echo "<input type='text' value='$choice'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first load the page, there are no POST data, so you could set `$choice` to the first book in list:

```
$choice = isset($_POST['books']) ? $_POST['books'] : $books->book[0]->code;
```

But you have to udnerstand the difference between PHP and JavaScript in here.

PHP can only change the value, when there is a request on the server as it is a server-side language. If you wish to update the value instantly, without submiting the form, you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if it must be purely PHP, then put a submit button on your form for when a selection is made.  This will set the value you are looking for.  Others have provided samples on how to do this form submission automatically with javascript, but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP, it looks as though you're just missing the submit button to actually post the selection.

To submit the form without a submit button, you need to use javascript, eg.

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">....</select>
```

Below is a simple example (static options rather than xml) that also sets the selected option in the select (IMO this is a more practical use than printing it in the text input)

```
<?php
$val = isset($_REQUEST['books']) ? $_REQUEST['books'] : null;
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="books" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value=>Choose a book</option>
        <option<?php if($val && $val === 'opt 1'){ print ' selected';}?>>opt 1</option>
        <option<?php if($val && $val === 'opt 2'){ print ' selected';}?>>opt 2</option>
    </select>

    <noscript><button type="submit">Submit</button></noscript>
</form>

<?php if($val){ ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['books']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

This is probably ok just for a school exercise, but in the real world you would probably want to sanitize any user input ($_REQUEST['book'] / $_POST['book']) and use a better templating engine than vanilla PHP (I like Twig) to help separate presentation from functional logic.

Comment: Nice. this.form.submit() does it. A submit button would work, but I was curious how you would do it without a submit button.